# USB gadget - functionfs: How to access endpoints utilizing flag FUNCTIONFS_VIRTUAL_ADDR

Tags: c++, linux, usb

I'm trying to utilize the [functionFS](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/usb/functionfs.txt) API to implement a custom USB device. I managed to set up the device descriptors with configFS as well as the interface and enpoint descriptors via functionFS.
To have a more deterministic endpoint numbering (functionFS does that in the background), I tried to use the flag FUNCTIONFS_VIRTUAL_ADDR, which names the endpoint files like "ep02" and "ep81" instead of "ep2" and "ep1".

My problem now is, as soon as I make use of the flag FUNCTIONFS_VIRTUAL_ADDR, I cannot receive bulk transfers anymore. Endpoint files are there (in my case "/mnt/ffs/ep02" and "/mnt/ffs/ep81") but reading the ep02 file doesn't return any content.

Does anyone have any experience with this?

cheers benjo

I have sniffed the traffic with wireshark and can see a bulk transfer from the host to endpoint 0x02 but my device never sees this.

```
void Usb::dumpThread()
{
    std::ofstream ep1File(m_ffsPath + "/ep81");
    std::ifstream ep2File(m_ffsPath + "/ep02");

    static std::array<char, maxPacketSize> buffer;
    while (true)
    {
        ep2File.getline(&buffer[0], buffer.size(), '\0');
        if (ep2File.gcount() > 0)
        {
            std::cout << "Received " << ep2File.gcount() << " bytes." << std::endl;
            std::cout << reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&buffer[0]) << std::endl;
            std::string command(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&buffer[1]));

            if (command == "ABC")
            {
                // do sth.
            }
}
```